# Why is the domain of $x^2$ the set of all real numbers?

Tags: functions, polynomials, square-numbers

I try to understand, why domain of $x^2$ is the set of all real numbers.

My doubts:
The domain of square root is not defined for negative numbers. Reason to that (If I am not wrong) is that function is supposed to have output with only one input leading to it. Therefore 9 cannot be square-rooted to -3 and 3, only to the positive number (in this case it's 3). Is not the situation with  $x^2$ the same? Should not a domain for it be limited to non-negative numbers? Otherwise, we are having an ambiguity of 3 and -3 leading to 9...

Comment: What is the _definition_ of the domain of a function? Once you have that, the answer is immediate.

Comment: the domain of $x^2$ is the set of all real numbers, this is right

Comment: @quasi a set of inputs?

Comment: The set of all _possible_ inputs. Is there any number $x$ that you can't plug in to get a result? The domain is not concerned with the nature of the results. As long as there is a result, the input is legal.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner, but why? Why do we have a domain for squared root limited to non-negative numbers and here not?

Comment: @quasi, thanks for answering. But why do we limit the domain with square roots then? is not the situation here the same?

Comment: for the $$\sqrt{x}$$ we must have $$x\geq 0$$ if $x$ is negative, then we get a complex number pair

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner, thank you for answering. I read that one of the reasons for that domain limitation of squared root is that both -3 and 3 as input lead to the 9. Is not situation here the same? As to 9 in codomain will lead both 3 and -3 leading to the ambiguitiy?

Comment: If the course is precalculus or calculus, only real outputs are allowed, so you can't plug a negative number into a square root. But can square a negatrive number. The fact that $(-3)^2$ and $3^2$ yield the same output doesn't in any way disqualify $-3$ and $3$ as inputs.

Comment: @quasi, I totally agree with the limitation of the domain on squared root. I just don't understand why is not situation the same with  $x^2$...

Comment: Show me a real number that you can't square.

Comment: @quasi, thanks for answering. I agree with you and see your point. Maybe I was wrong about the reason why square root domain is limited to only non-negative numbers. I thought that this is because of possible ambiguity (two numbers such as -3 and 3 leading to one number 9). I think I was wrong. Based on this wrong assumption I made wrong conclusions on $x^2$ function..

Comment: Yes, a function needs one output for every legal input. What you said: "for each output, only one input" is not the correct concept of a function. In other words, using arrows, for each legal input, an arrow has to go from that input to some output. It can't split and go to two different outputs. However, two or more inputs can share the same output. As an extreme example, consider a constant function, say $f(x) = 4$. Then every input goes to the output $4$.

Comment: @quasi, thank you. Now I understand

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're right about one thing: the square root function is the inverse function to the squaring function, *after the squaring function is restricted* to a domain on which it's one-to-one.  That domain is nonnegative numbers.

However, I think you're overthinking this problem.  When a problem asks for the the domain of a function defined by an algebraic expression, the task is to calculate the entire subset of real numbers which can be substituted into the expression.  For instance, if the expression is $\frac{1}{1-x^2}$, you're supposed to notice that the denominator cannot be zero for this to make sense. So the domain must carve out any numbers which do that, namely $\pm 1$.  Therefore the domain is $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{-1,1\}$.

But the expression you're given is just $x^2$.  This is defined for all real numbers.  So the domain is $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 5):

The domain is $\Bbb R$, the set of all real numbers. The two inputs $\pm3$ both have output $9$, yes, but this doesn't stop either from being an input: $x^2$ still a function.

Answer (score 2):

A function $f$ on a set $X$ is a subset of the cartesian product of $X$ with itself such that if $(x,y) \in f$ and $(x,z) \in f$ then $y=z$. The domain of $f$ is the set $d$ of left coordinates of ordered pairs of $f$. In short, the domain is something you can have the distinct privilege of specifying.

I.e. if you have a function $f$ and a domain $d$ such that $d$ has more than, (for example, $10$ real numbers). Then you can create a new function $g$ by creating a new domain $d'$ by removing one element from $d$ and setting $g$ equal to the restriction of values of $f$ defined over $d'$.

In short, one domain for the function $f(x)=x^{2}$ is $\mathbb{R}$ because for each real number $x$ in the domain you get a unique real number, (namely $x^2$.)

You might opine that this is a "natural" domain for the function. But then again, we can specify the same equation defining the function $f$ and just restrict our domain set $d$ to be a new domain, $d = \{274848638463926284\} $ instead of all of $\mathbb{R}$ and the result is still a domain for $f(x)=x^{2}$. Although, the graph of this function is a single point in the plane-- which is rather boring compared to a parabola.

Answer (score 2):

> I try to understand, why domain of $x^2$ is the set of all real numbers.

The key idea is to distinguish these two things:

- the [image of the function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_(mathematics)), i.e. the "output" of the function, and here you're right: it's **not** $\mathbb{R}$, but $\mathbb{R}^+$
- the [domain of definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_of_a_function), i.e. the set of all authorized numbers as "input" of the function: here all real numbers can be squared. Can $2.317$ be squared? Yes. Can $-3$ be squared? Yes. Indeed: $(-3)^2 = -3 \times (-3) = 9$. Thus the domain of definition of the function $x \mapsto x^2$ is $\mathbb{R}$.